# How to convert JSON Object to JSON Array

Tags: java, html, arrays, json, arraylist

Hi I have a JSON Object contains data Like

```
{"THIRD":"OK","SECOND":"OK","FIRST":"OK"}
{"THIRD":"OK","SECOND":"NULL","FIRST":"OK"}
{"THIRD":"OK","SECOND":"OK","FIRST":"OK"}
```

When I tried to add this JSON object to JSON array it is only taking last one in JSON Object({"THIRD":"OK","SECOND":"OK","FIRST":"OK"}).Can any one help me in solving this.

I am using it like

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
array.add(object);(Only adding last element in JSON Object)
```

Instead of taking all values in the JSON Object Json Array is only taking last value in JSON Object.

Comment: Add commata at the end of the first two lines.

Comment: that isn't a JSONObject, its a set of lines that each line is a JSONObject

Comment: Thought it was a single response.

Comment: you need to like this ...

    array.push(object);

Comment: There is no such option like array.push @roshini

Comment: take var array = [];
array.push(object);
like that  while iterating time you can add object...
else can you add your code here

Comment: check this link..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33763051/why-i-can-not-save-the-json-object-into-the-json-array

Comment: Thanks :) Roshini garu.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution:

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
     JSONObject sec=new JSONObject();
     sec.put("THIRD","OK");
     sec.put("SECOND","OK");
     sec.put("FIRST","OK");
     array.put(sec);
}
```

You have to make JSONObject every time then add it to JSONArray