# Why i can not save the json object into the json array?

Tags: android, json

I'm beginner in android,write simple application to send json array to server,write this code:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            String DATABASE_NAME = "TEMPFOOD";
            String TABLE_NAME = "tempData";
            try{
                SQLiteDatabase mydb = openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, TempActivity.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
                Cursor allrows  = mydb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+  TABLE_NAME, null);
                if(allrows.moveToFirst()){
                    do{
                        String Food_Name = allrows.getString(0);
                        String Value = allrows.getString(1);
                        String NOBAT = allrows.getString(2);
                        String TIME = allrows.getString(3);
                        String DATE = allrows.getString(4);
                        try {
                            obj.put("Food_Name", Food_Name)
                                    .put("Value", Value)
                                    .put("NOBAT", NOBAT)
                                    .put("TIME", TIME)
                                    .put("DATE", DATE);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        jsonArray.put(obj);
                    }
                    while(allrows.moveToNext());
                }
                mydb.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            String jsonText = jsonArray.toString();
```

for example i read 4 record from `sqlite`,save into the `jsonArray` latest record,why?how can i solve that?thanks.

Comment: Is select query working?

Comment: yes my friend ,select work

Comment: So your jsonArray is empty or what?

Comment: @DhavalPatel jsonArray just save latest record

Comment: try putting JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(); inside do-while loop. I think it's happening because you are using same JSONObject. just like List.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is only storing the last record because you are not creating a new `JSONObject` in your `do...while` loop. See my edited code.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        String DATABASE_NAME = "TEMPFOOD";
        String TABLE_NAME = "tempData";
        try{
            SQLiteDatabase mydb = openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, TempActivity.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
            Cursor allrows  = mydb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+  TABLE_NAME, null);
            if(allrows.moveToFirst()){
                do{
                    obj = new JSONObject();
                    String Food_Name = allrows.getString(0);
                    String Value = allrows.getString(1);
                    String NOBAT = allrows.getString(2);
                    String TIME = allrows.getString(3);
                    String DATE = allrows.getString(4);
                    try {
                        obj.put("Food_Name", Food_Name)
                                .put("Value", Value)
                                .put("NOBAT", NOBAT)
                                .put("TIME", TIME)
                                .put("DATE", DATE);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    jsonArray.put(obj);
                }
                while(allrows.moveToNext());
            }
            mydb.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        String jsonText = jsonArray.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example to show use of `Gson` library

make a `Record.java` class

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Record {

    @SerializedName("Name")
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("password")
    private String password;

    @SerializedName("item1")
    private String item1;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getItem1() {
        return item1;
    }

    public void setItem1(String item1) {
        this.item1 = item1;
    }
}
```

make a test for this `RecordTestDrive.java`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class RecordTestDrive {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Record> records = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            Record record = new Record();
            record.setName("Name_"+i);
            record.setPassword("password_"+i);
            record.setItem1("item_"+i);
            records.add(record);
        }

        String jsonResult = (new Gson()).toJson(records);
        System.out.println(""+jsonResult);

    }
}
```

output==>

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Name_0",
    "password": "password_0",
    "item1": "item_0"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Name_1",
    "password": "password_1",
    "item1": "item_1"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Name_2",
    "password": "password_2",
    "item1": "item_2"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Name_3",
    "password": "password_3",
    "item1": "item_3"
  }
]
```

In this manner once you have data read from the `SQLite` database into your objects, after which you can easily make array of `JSON` String from the data you have gathered from the database to send it to server